# CGpoint Vs CGPointMake

Tags: swift, cgpoint

I have recently been introduced to swift.

A question, when to use CGPoint and when shall I use CGPointMake ?

I have interchanged these two statements and they both returned the same result

```
 self.anchorPoint  = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)

 self.anchorPoint  = CGPoint(0.5, 0.5)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Every struct in Swift gets an automatically created member-wise initializer. So, because `struct CGPoint` exists with members `x` and `y`, you can do:

```
 self.anchorPoint  = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
```

(Note that you can't actually do `CGPoint(0.5, 0.5)` -- that gets a compile error because initializers require labels for all parameters, except where otherwise declared.)

In Swift 1.x-2.x, `CGPointMake` was a function imported from the C version of this API.  In Swift 3,  the initializer form is the only way to create a `CGPoint` -- it's one of the changes to make [CoreGraphics](http://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics) much more Swifty.

Comment: *"because C doesn't have member-wise initializers like Swift does"* - not quite, you have a ["compound literal"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) `self.anchorpoint = (CGPoint){ 0.5, 0.5 };`, but that is relatively new.

Comment: C99 also has the `{.x = 0.5, .y = 0.5}` syntax.

Comment: @jtbandes: Yes, but that is (if I remember correctly) a "designated initializer". You can use it to define and init a struct `CGPoint p = {.x = 0.5, .y = 0.5}`, but not as an expression in an assignment. `self.anchorpoint = {.x = 0.5, .y = 0.5}` does not compile.

Comment: It does if you cast it!

Comment: @rickster The OP linked here from a tutorial saying he didn't really understand your answer. Would you consider editing to remove terminology which relies on the assumption that the reader knows anything about C / swift. For example, what do you meant by "struct" and "member-wise initializers"? These are terms I'm not familiar with, and expect the OP isn't familiar with either.

Answer (score 3):

When you cmd-click on the type Xcode opens the file with the definition.

`CGPoint` is a struct:

```
struct CGPoint {
    var x: CGFloat
    var y: CGFloat
}
```

and `CGPointMake` is just a function which creates a `CGPoint` and returns it:

```
func CGPointMake(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) -> CGPoint
```